# Mid-point ratio on graph

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions, ratio

I have two points $(4,-5)$ and $(0,7)$ and I'm supposed to use the ratio $1:3$ to place it on the grid. Could you please show both the normal equation and one using the example coordinates?

Comment: What specific question do you have about the topic? What do you need to know for you to be able to complete this on your own?  What don't you understand? Please be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A = (4,-5)$, and $B = (0,7) $, then a point $P = (x, y) $ on $AB$ is given by

$ P = (1 - t) A + t B $ where $ 0 \le t \le 1 $

Note that

$AP = P - A = - t A + t B = t (B - A) $ and

$PB = B - P = (1 - t)A + (t - 1) B = (t - 1) (B - A) $

So we want

$ \dfrac{t}{|t - 1|} = \dfrac{t}{1 -t } = \dfrac{1}{3} $

From here, it follow that $ 3 t = 1 - t$ which give us $ t = \dfrac{1}{4} $

Substituting this, we get

$ P = \left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right) (4, -5) + \left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right) (0, 7) = ( 3 , \dfrac{ -15 + 7 }{4} ) = \boxed{ (3, -2)} $